# How do I replace pandas rows with values of another dataframe for all instances of the value in the first df?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
df1=
A   B   C
a   1   3
b   2   3
c   2   2
a   1   4
```

```
df2=
A   B   C
a   1   3.5
```

Now I need to replace all occurrences of `a` in `df1` (2 in this case) with `a` in `df2`, leaving `b` and `c` unchanged. The final dataframe should be:

```
df_final=
A   B   C
b   2   3
c   2   2
a   1   3.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
df_final = pd.concat((df1[df1['A'].ne('a')], df2))
```

Or if you have several values like `a`:

```
list_special = ['a']
df_final = pd.concat((df1[~df1['A'].isin(list_special)], df2))
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Not exactly, there are several values like `'a'`.

Comment: This matches your expected output with the sample data. Maybe you want to update them to reflect what you mean. Also see updates.

Answer (score 0):

If `df2` just has the average of duplicated values, you can do `df1.groupby(["A", "B"]).mean().reset_index()`

Otherwise, you can do something like this:

```
In [27]: df = df1.groupby(["A", "B"]).first().merge(df2, how="left", on=["A", "
    ...: B"])
    ...: df["C"] = df["C_y"].fillna(df["C_x"])
    ...: df = df[["A", "B", "C"]]
    ...: df
Out[27]:
   A  B    C
0  a  1  3.5
1  b  2  3.0
2  c  2  2.0
```